# Easier way to .find nested xml node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

The following works but it seems like there should be a shortcut or easier way to find the desired XML node by attribute other than nesting .each loops. Is there?

**Abbreviated XML:**

```
<year>
  <month id="January">
    <day id="1" />
    <day id="2" />
    <day id="3">
      <hour id="1">Stack Overflow</hour>
    </day>
  </month>
</year>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "xmlTest.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: parseXml
});

function parseXml(xml) {
  $(xml).find("month[id='January']").each(function() {
    $(this).find("day[id='1']").each(function() {
      $("#output").html($(this).find("hour[id='1']").text());
    });
  });
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much Will. I knew there had to be a way but couldn't find an example to save my life.

Comment: Follow up question. How do I do the same but get the month by index instead of id? .find('month.eq(i) day[id="1"]...) doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function parseXml(xml){
    var text = $(xml).find('month[id="January"] day[id="1"] hour[id="1"]').text();
    $("#output").html(text);
}
```